# $pull data from a double nested schema

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

from the below schema ,

how do i delete out one specific **answer comment** ??

```js
const Schemaa = mongoose.Schema({
  
    questionBody: String,
    Comment:[{
       commentBody: String,   
    }],
    answer: [{
        answerBody: String,
        Comment:[{
            commentBody:String,    /// i want to delete one specific comment having a unique
        }]                         ///  'Object _id.
    }]
})
export default mongoose.model("Questions", Schemaa)
```

I used the below code, to **Add a comment in answers section** and it worked fine...

```js
const updatedQuestion = await Schemaa.updateOne(
            { 'answer._id' : answerId},              /// I passed that specific answer's _id   
            { $push: {                               ///  as answerId
           "answer.$.Comment": { 
             commentBody}
            } 
           })
```

regards.

Comment: You know you can pass a condition to [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#-pull)

Comment: yes, i used that too...for deleting a particular `answer` , but since deleting an `answer comment` is double nested , i'm still struggling with that :(

Comment: Try $pull with the same field name you used for $push

Comment: yeahh...its working now, thank you so much...(actually i used   `/comment/deleteacomment/:id` in index.js, whereas i wrote it wrong in the controllers section...was getting 404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

caught the error, its working with this now...

```js
await Questions.updateOne(
            { 'answer._id': answerId},{
                $pull:{
                    'answer.$.Comment' : { '_id' :commentId}
                }
            }
        )
```